# Need help creating a txt log file in Python

Tags: python, logging

I am stuck on an assignment:  We have to make a password checker with a txt log file logging the time and date a password was put it, but only if the password doesn't meet the requirements to be accepted.

The password checker code is below, I need some help with logging to a file.

```py
PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 6
PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH = 14

password = input("Enter your password: ")

password_length = len(password)

while password_length < PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH or password_length > PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH:
    print("Error - password out of range")
    password = input("Enter new password between 6 and 14 characters: ")
    password_length = len(password)

if password.isdigit():
    message = "your password is too weak"
elif password.isalpha():
    message = "your password is too weak"
else:
    message = "your password is strong"

print(f"{message} your password length was: {password_length}")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: I remember answering a very similar question to this.

Comment: have you considered using logging module?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `f = open("file.txt", "w")` for creating and writing to a text file, if the file with the name `file.txt` already exists, it will not create a new one but it finds that file and writes to it. To start writing to the file, simply use `f.write("Your message")`. When finished, use `f.close()` to close the file.

As an answer to your question, you can create a function that logs the password given to it to a text file. I have create the following function to write the password to a text file:

```
from datetime import datetime

def logPassword(password, filename):
    f = open(filename, "a")
    f.write("{0} -- {1}\n".format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), password))
    f.close()
```

The function writes the date, time and password in the following format to the txt file:

```
2019-04-18 09:58 -- test1
2019-04-18 09:58 -- test2
2019-04-18 09:58 -- test3
```

The `"a"` in the `open(filename, "a")` function means that you are appending to the text file so nothing in the file will be overwritten.

To use this function in your code just call it when validating the password.